# Replacing functions (text) on fabricjs canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I have two functions that each draw text but I'd like whichever function is clicked to replace the currently drawn one (so that there is only one drawn at a time). How might I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

```js
 var $ = function(id) {
   return document.getElementById(id)
 };

 var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
 canvas.setHeight(300);
 canvas.setWidth(500);
 
 function textOne() {
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('One', {
     left: 50,
     top: 100,
     fontFamily: 'arial',
     fill: '#333',
     fontSize: 50
   }));
 }

 function textTwo() {
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Two', {
     left: 200,
     top: 100,
     fontFamily: 'arial black',
     fill: '#333',
     fontSize: 50
   }));
 }
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="textOne()">One</button>
<button onclick="textTwo()">Two</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Have you've solved your problem now?

Comment: No, I haven’t yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `clear` method on your given `canvas` element so that your given `canvas` context can clear the contents inside in your `current text drawings`

JS Code:

```
 var $ = function(id) {
     return document.getElementById(id)
 };

 var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
 canvas.setHeight(300);
 canvas.setWidth(500);

 function textOne() {
     canvas.clear(); // Clear the given canvas
     canvas.add(new fabric.IText('One', {
         left: 50,
         top: 100,
         fontFamily: 'arial',
         fill: '#333',
         fontSize: 50
     }));
 }

 function textTwo() {
     canvas.clear(); // Clear the given canvas
     canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Two', {
         left: 200,
         top: 100,
         fontFamily: 'arial black',
         fill: '#333',
         fontSize: 50
     }));
 }
```

Here's a JS Fiddle for a given example: http://jsfiddle.net/7me0eat3

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! If I wanted some other function to persist, like other text for example, how would I get it to remain? [Here's a JSFiddle with a third function](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/9t3gn533/2/). I can also create a new question, if you'd like. Thanks again!

Comment: You want to have a `given text drawing` to remain on the same `canvas` element?

Comment: Yes, is that possible?

Comment: This one is a different case. I would suggest to create a new question in regards for this one. Some guys might also help in this kind of scenario

Comment: Okay, I will do :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);
var text = new fabric.IText('One', {
   left: 50,
   top: 100,
   fontFamily: 'arial',
   fill: '#333',
   fontSize: 50
 });
canvas.add(text);
function replaceText(val) {
 text.setText(val);
 canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="replaceText('One')">One</button>
<button onclick="replaceText('Two')">Two</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

You can set text to text object with text property or use `setText()`.